# Is it possible to connect a NodeMCU to a 3G network, and if so, how?

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, 4g, 3g-network

I have a NodeMCU microcontroller.

Question 1: Is it possible to connect this to a 3G network? 
Question 2: How? Please could someone provide me the example code for connecting to it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ESP8266 (the MCU used by the NodeMCU boards) connects to WiFi but not GPRS unless you add extra hardware i.e. a GPRS modem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I guess I'd better get one of those then!

Comment: Ok, don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer so Stack Overflow can mark it as closed.